# Python Requests 403 error in one environment and not another?

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm working on a web scraping project using Python Requests library to fetch data from a public API. I'm able to fetch the data I want without error from my local machine, but when I try to fetch from the same endpoint on Google Colab, I am receiving a 403 response. Not sure how to proceed as I am specifying the user-agent in the request in both instances already.

I'm scraping data from DraftKings as follows:

```python
def dk_fetch_matchup_props(league_name, prop_types):
  matchup_props = []
  league_code = "103"
  url = "https://sportsbook.draftkings.com/api/odds/v1/leagues/" + league_code + "/offers/props.json"
  s = requests.Session()
  s.headers.update({'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36'})
  response = s.get(url)
  print(response.text)
```

Comment: Can you post the website link?

Comment: Perhaps the site doesn't want to be spammed by bot requests from Google Colab?

Comment: I've updated the OP with my code for further analysis

Comment: Opening the link in the browser showed access denied

Comment: with this link -- https://sportsbook.draftkings.com/api/odds/v1/leagues/103/offers/props.json ? I'm able to open it in browser and see the json response